# What is the most up-to-date way to create an alarm clock/timer app in Android?

Tags: android

This is something I have been trying for a long time but have never been able to entirely get to work chiefly because of the inability to make the timer accurate. I am wanting to build an Android desk clock-type application which allows one to set a timer and then have it go off *reliably* after the interval requested with audio notification, i.e. you set it, let it run, then when the time runs out the device starts beeping to let you know the time is up and/or put a notification on screen.

The trick is that, particularly in the newer versions of Android, there seem to be a variety of different power management and anti-malware features to contend with that seem to make it quite difficult, and other threads here about building alarm clocks are quite old and thus useless in the face of rapid and ongoing changes to the API by Google.

Strategies that I've tried so far include running a service with foreground notification and using the alarm manager (and yes even with the "setExact" stuff which, apparently the API docs say actually *isn't* what it says on the tin because of these throttling features!), but in either case, particularly once the device falls asleep, the alarm may sometimes work but other times it goes off belatedly if at all, and this random, inconsistent behavior is clearly not acceptable.

Is there a robust (or as robust as possible) way to make a user-notifying timer as of 2021, compatible with, say, API levels 18 to 30? Note that I've tried looking at open source source code for the DeskClock app but it's not the most friendly code and moreover it has many more features than I'd want to have in this simpler app, which makes it hard to figure out what all are the essential bits. It does seem the alarm manager is used, but I'm not sure how they're getting *exact* timeout.

Answer (score 0):

> Strategies that I've tried so far include running a service with foreground notification and using the alarm manager (and yes even with the "setExact" stuff which, apparently the API docs say actually isn't what it says on the tin because of these throttling features!)

The [documentation for setExact](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager#setExact(int,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) explicitly states (emphasis mine):

> Schedule an alarm to be delivered **precisely** at the stated time.
>
> This method is like set(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent), but **does not permit the OS to adjust the delivery time**. The alarm will be delivered **as nearly as possible to the requested trigger time**.

It doesn't say anything about throttling.

Further, it goes on (again, emphasis mine):

> Note: only alarms for which there is a strong demand for exact-time delivery (**such as an alarm clock ringing at the requested time**) should be scheduled as exact.

Is that not what you're looking for?